# What is the correct *first* interpretation of the time derivative of some measurable quantity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation, observables, time-evolution

For example, take the position function $x(t)$. When I take $(d/dt)(x(t))$, I know that I must ultimately conclude that the result is the velocity function $v(t)$. But this feels like a ''jump ahead'' in the logical flow of thought and I don't want to skip steps. What is the *first* thing I should think of as the result of the time derivative of some quantity? Going straight to the conclusion of ''the velocity function'' will not help me in other situations where I don't know of a ''nice conclusion''.

Based on what little I know of physics, math, and derivatives, I think the first conclusion I should come to is that the result is the rate at which the original function changes in an infinitesimal interval of time. Is this the correct *first* interpretation?

Comment: -1. What you "should" do, which conclusions are "nice", and which interpretation is "correct" are all subjective questions. Whether your interpretation should be the 1st one or the 10th also has no objective meaning, as far as I can see. This does not seem to be a question about physics.

Comment: What meaningful difference is there between "velocity" and "rate at which the [position] changes in an infinitesimal interval of time"? All your "first interpretation" does is not substitute "position" for "original function".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your conclusion is correct, the first thing one should think is a ratio: the derivative of a quantity $q(t)$ with respect to time is the variation $dq = q(t+dt)-q(t)$ of the quantity during a small time interval $dt$ divided by $dt$, that is, the ratio $dq/dt$. Passing to the limit when $t \to 0$ is then a convenient way to treat this ratio.

Answer (score 1):

A *measurable quantity* is a rather vague term, and there are many notions of differentiation as well depending on what we mean. For example, one may consider the derivative,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle Q \rangle = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle [Q,H]\rangle + \bigg\langle \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle$$

of the expectation value of an operator in quantum mechanics, which obviously has a different interpretation from simply the derivative of a function. Nevertheless, sticking to the simple case you seem to be considering, that is, a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the derivative is,

$$\frac{df}{dt} = \lim_{\delta t \to 0}\frac{f(t+\delta t)-f(t)}{\delta t}$$

which we interpret as the rate at which $f$ changes over time. For $f$ being the position of say, a particle, $\dot f$ corresponds to the velocity, $\ddot{f}$ acceleration, and so forth.

Comment: You seem to have a pretty through answer as is, so I just have a suggestion to improve it slightly.  Everyone here is treating the derivative as strictly a change in quantity _with respect to time_ when really it can be with respect to any other quantity; the t should be an arbitrary quantity, not specifically time.

Comment: @JMac I am *very* aware, note my answer starts with *there are many notions of differentiation.* One can take a functional derivative with respect to a function, or a covariant derivative using the Levi-Civita connection, or a Lie derivative, an exterior derivative; the list is endless. But the question is specific to time, and I don't think generalising will enlighten the OP. The main message is clear: it gives the rate at which something changes with respect to the parameter, and in more exotic cases the interpretation changes of course.